# ui-router creating state by query parmeters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm just getting starting with ui-router, and I'm trying to create nested state based on the existence of a query parameter. Something like:

```
$stateProvider.state('baz.foo', {
    url: '?bar',
    templateUrl: 'partials/bazfoo.html'
});
```

If I then navigate to `www.mydomain.com/?foo=bar` it should activate that state, but it doesn't seem to be working.

How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

I ended up doing "redirects" with something like:

```
.state('loading', {
    url: "/?foo&bar",
    template: 'loading...',
    controller: function($state, $stateParams) {
        if($stateParams['foo']) {
            $state.go('baz.foo', $stateParams);
            return;
        }

        if($stateParams['bar']) {
            $state.go('baz.bar', $stateParams);
            return;
        }

        $state.go('qux');
    }
})
```

Found this solution at [AngularJS : Pass data to state with $state.go in angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027636/pass-data-to-state-with-state-go-in-angular-ui-router)

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using HTML5 or hashbang mode? If hashbang then it will need to be `#?foo=bar`.

Comment: HTML5 mode is on. But it looks like my example was too simplistic. The state I'm after is a nested state, baz.foo, not a top level state. That, I'm guessing is where the problem is. Is this possible, or is there a way to create a state that simply redirects to 'baz.foo'?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to create a single state when a query value is present. Queries should be used as optional inputs to the current state.

Comment: For example: a password reset code. Upon requesting a password reset code, the user receives an email with a link in it. That link is in the form, "www.domain.com?code=123". Hitting that URL, which cannot be changed, has to take the user into the settings.userManagement.changePassword state, and make the 'code' parameter available.