# AngularJS : writing ui-router $state data into ancestor $state for sibling access

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a customer management interface that I'm trying to write using ui-router. I have some states set up as

```
"csp"
"csp.search"
"csp.customer"
"csp.customer.details"
"csp.customer.status"
```

How can I use `ui-router`'s `$state` `data` to take the `csp.search` result and provide it to the rest of `csp` and/or `csp.customer`? As I understand it, the data would need to be on the closest common ancestor, `csp`, but there's no easy/clean way to do that that I can find.

I know I can make everything a child state of `csp.search`, so that they would inherit `$state.current.data`. I could also parse `$state.current.name` for the first name before the `.`, but how universal is that? Further still, I think I could write something that climbs up the ancestry (`$state.$current.parent`) until finding some "top-most" signal, but I don't know what that should be.

Is there a more elegant, Angular solution?

Edit: The same question might be asked, given a known state, e.g. `csp`, how can I add data to it from any controller?

Comment: I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20029731/356016, but it seems to rely on the the `$scope`/View hierarchy instead of `$state` data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `csp.search` results would be on a $scope. If $scopes in additional controllers need to share the model/state/data referenced by that $scope, use a singleton object instance by registering a angular service. That one factory can be injected into as many controllers as you like, and then everything can work off that one source of truth.

Heres a simple demo of a factory sharing an Object between controllers with ui-router http://plnkr.co/edit/P2UudS?p=preview (left tab only)

Factory & Controllers:

```
app.factory('uiFieldState', function () {
    return {uiObject: {data: null}}
});

app.controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiFieldState', '$stateParams', '$state',
    function($scope, uiFieldState, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.selected = uiFieldState.uiObject;
    }
]);

app.controller('LeftTabACtrl', ['$scope', 'uiFieldState', '$stateParams', '$state',
    function($scope, uiFieldState, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.selected2 = uiFieldState.uiObject;
    }
]);
```

The factory object `{uiObject: {data: null}}` is injected into the controller with `uiFieldState` & then its simply `$scope.selected = uiFieldState.uiObject;` for connecting the factory to the scope `ng-model="selected.data"` .

This is a pretty good tutorial on angularJS services: http://ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html

Comment: I understand Angular services, and that's what I have in place from using ngRoute. I thought ui-router might provide a way to use its `$state` `data` for similar purpose, as asked in my rephrased question.

Comment: In my mind, $state (and that data object in the ui-router .config) are for `page` scaffolding outside the `<body></body>`, and the flow from page to page. To answer your question, given a known state, injecting a service into the `controller` namespaced in the $state Object is how you append search data.